# How to set a cell in Excel to a particular date format using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I need to show the date in excel sheet in following format:

[image]

The values are being set but sometimes they appear as

[image]

How can I programmatically set the format of date displayed to DD/MM/YYYY ?

Comment: You'll probably have to set the format explicitly using NumberFormat on the range.

range.NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
=TEXT("7-20-2019", "DD/MM/YYYY")
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably have to set the format explicitly using NumberFormat on the range.

```
range.NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY";
```